# can we consume build artifacts of 1 pipeline into another pipeline of different repos in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Assume we have 2 git repos in Azure DevOps "RepoA" and "RepoB".
RepoA has few class library projects whose references are being used in main project which is in RepoB.
So in Azure Pipeline can we create a Build of RepoA and this build output can be used by another pipeline configured for RepoB build?
I am using clasic build template.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In the build pipeline for RepoB, you can use the [**Download Pipeline Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) to download the artifacts from the latest or specified build of RepoA.

1. In the build pipeline for RepoA, after building the class library, use the [**Publish Pipeline Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) to publish the artifacts as as a pipeline artifact.

   [image]
2. In the build pipeline for RepoB, before the build task, add the **Download Pipeline Artifacts task** to download artifacts from from the latest or specified build version of RepoA.

   [image]